# render() not rendering template

Tags: python, django

I have a simple web app that contains two buttons that each make a post request through jQuery. I listen for the POST request in my `views.py` and based on what button has been pressed I perform certain logic. For example:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    foo = request.POST['SELECTED'] #the value of the button pressed
    if foo == 'I got gas!':
        try:
            return render(request, 'gogetgas/toosoon.html')
        except Exception as e:
            print e
...
```

This is just a snippet of the logic but it's the relevant part. When I debug it it gets to `return render()` and carries out all the logic. However it doesn't load my `toosoon.html` template. There are no errors thrown in the console and no exceptions printed. Both Chrome's console and the Django console print out that it was a successful POST request using jQuery logs and Python print respectively.

Why won't it display my page?

**EDIT**

My jQuery code as requested (I appreciate it's a bit roundabout but my buddy wrote it and I don't want to trim it until I have everything working):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            return false;
        });


 $("form input[type='button']").one('click', function(e){

    var selected = $(this).val();

    console.log(selected);

    submitForm(selected);

 });


 function submitForm(sel){

     var selected =sel;
     console.log(selected);

     $.post("/", {selected: sel},function(){

     }).done(function(){
       console.log('success');
     }).fail(function(err){
       console.log(err.responseText);
     });


 }

    });
</script>
```

I was wrong in referring to it as a Template of sorts. It's a simple HTML file found in `<project root>/templates/gogetgas/toosoon.html`.

**ANSWER**

To clarify further on Daniel Roseman's answer below I had to do something with jQuery to load the response. I got confused and thought the Django `render` would load the page somehow without the need for jQuery. I created a variable to post the ajax request then on the `.done` callback I empty the body and fill it with the data:

```
var xhr = $.post("/", {selected:selected});

xhr.done(function(data){
    console.log('done');
    $('body').empty().html(data);
 });
```

Comment: Can you post the template and the relevant jQuery code? It may very well be a problem with handling the response in jQUery.

Comment: Do you have debug set to true? Also I think wraping return inside try/except is bad.

Comment: Updated my post. Debug is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code in your jQuery script that would display the result of the POST. An AJAX query will go and get the data asynchronously, but you need to actually do something with whatever the browser returns.

Comment: How would I do this? I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Comment: Well, SO isn't a "write my code" service. If you're going to be programming in jQuery, you'll need to learn it. But as a hint, you need some code in the `.done()` function (which should accept a `data` parameter) which takes that data and inserts it into the page somewhere.

Comment: It's a good job I didn't ask you to write my code for me then. I was asking for something I could Google. Thanks for the hint, it's the push I was asking for.

Comment: I've posted my solution above. Thanks again.